# Create array of bytes

Tags: assembly, nios

I'm trying to create an array in memory to store bytes. I can do it with words with the following code

You can test the code here https://cpulator.01xz.net/?sys=nios-de1soc

```
.text
.global _start
_start:
    movia r8, PATH
    movi r4, 0xE
    stw r4, 0(r8)
    stw r4, 4(r8)

.data
ARRAY:
    .skip 10
```

When i change the line `stw r4, 4(r8)` with `stw r4, 1(r8)` it gives me the error `Warning: stw address 00000031 is misaligned`. I mostly understand the concept of misalignment, but is there any way of specifying in `.skip 10` that it should be `.byte` and not `.word`? Thanks

Comment: You want `stb` for storing a byte, not `stw`.

Comment: @Jester perfect thanks could you write as answer so i can put as solved